# Rails connect oracle raise error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, oracle11g, ubuntu-12.04

In my Rails app,I need to use oracle database.I installed the oracle 11g client successfully.I can connect the oracle server through:

```
sqlplus SFUSER/sfuser@SF
```

Then I connect oracle in Rails:

In  `databse.yml`:

```
development:
adapter: oracle_enhanced 
database: 192.168.0.154/SF
username: SFUSER
password: sfuser
```

In my `Gemfile`,I add

```
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.5.4'
gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.1.7'
```

and run `bundle install`
All gem are installed successfully.

But when I run:

```
rails s
```

I got:

```
/home/hxh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.5.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_column_dumper.rb:67:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ColumnDumper (NameError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I found this from activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter [github pages](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced)

> Oracle enhanced adapter version 1.5 just supports Rails 4 and does not
>   support Rails 3.2 or lower version of Rails.
>
> ...
>
> When using Ruby on Rails version 3 then in Gemfile include
>
> ```
> gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.4.0'
> ```

After running `bundle install`, `rails s` started to work.